# SQL Server query - not performing as expected, not behaving like I thought it would

Tags: sql-server, performance, query-performance

I have an advanced SQL question for your SQL perf gurus out there :-)

I'm currently trying to understand some behavior in a larger application, but it boils down to a query against these two tables:

- `Users` table - roughly 750 entries, `UserId` (`varchar(50)`) as clustered PK
- `ActionLog` table - millions of entries, includes `UserId` - but no FK relationship

For a grid in my ASP.NET application, I'm trying to get all users plus their last log entry's date.

The SQL statement that is currently being used looks something like this:

```
SELECT
     UserId, (other columns),
     LastLogDate = (SELECT TOP (1) [Timestamp] FROM dbo.ActionLog a WHERE a.UserId = u.UserId ORDER BY [Timestamp] DESC) 
FROM
     dbo.Users u;
```

and it returns the rows to display - but it's fairly slow (approx. 20 seconds).

My first thought was to add an index on the `ActionLog` table on `UserId` and to include the `Timestamp` column in it:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_UserId]
ON [dbo].[ActionLog]([UserId] ASC)
INCLUDE ([Timestamp])
```

The rows are now returned very quickly - under 2 seconds, with 350'000 entries in the `ActionLog` table, and my index is being used just fine, as the execution plan shows me. All seems fine.

Now, for approximating the production scenario, we loaded roughly 2 million rows into the `ActionLog` table, 95% or more of which refer to a non-existing user (i.e. these rows have a `UserId` that doesn't exist in the `Users` table).

Now suddenly, the query becomes **extremely slow** (24 minutes!), and the index isn't being used anymore.

I assumed that since the vast majority of the entries in the `ActionLog` table don't line up with an existing user, I would see performance gains if I use a **filtered** index - to "weed out" all those messy entries without a corresponding user - so I created this index (replacing the other one that existed before):

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_UserId]
ON [dbo].[Log]([UserId] ASC)
INCLUDE ([Timestamp])
WHERE UserId <> 'user'    -- that's the fixed, non-existing "UserId" I wanted to avoid
```

But to my dismay - the query is still about the same - takes over 20 minutes to complete. I updated the statistics - no change - still extremely slow.

Funny thing (to me) is: when I dropped the index and re-created it -> now the query was really fast again (again less than 3 seconds). WOW!

But as soon as I start adding more entries again, the query "tilts" and becomes really really slow.......

I don't fully understand why this is happening - I was thinking that with a filtered index that eliminates all those "rogue" entries, I would be seeing good performance on trying to find the newest `ActionLog` entry for existing users - but that doesn't seem to be the case.

**WHY NOT?**

Any ideas? Thoughts? Things to try??

Comment: Can you post or describe the execution plan when you drop and recreate index vs when you start adding more entries and it bogs down? Is it just deciding not to use the index after rows are added?

Comment: Try adding the filter expression to your correlated sub query `a.UserId <> 'user'`. I think the optimizer needs it to consider the filtered index.

Comment: There are some tips on how to create and use filtered indexes on MSDN. You could try to specify `WITH ( INDEX ( IDX_UserId ) )` at the end of the `SELECT` clause. Reference: [Create Filtered Indexes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280372.aspx)

Comment: I'm curious if adding OPTION(RECOMPILE) has any effect after rebuilding the index since you have already tried updating the statistics. My only other try would be to rebuild the query with a CTE joining on UserID getting the timestamp you want first hoping for a better permanent execution plan.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson: yes, that did the trick - thanks! But I learned that this has to work on SQL Server 2005 - so filtered indexes are out, unfortunately :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, `INCLUDE` here is not the best choice. You sort by entry date, but included columns aren't sorted. Better solution would be:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_ActionLog_UserIdTimestamp] ON [dbo].[ActionLog]
([UserId], [Timestamp]);
```

Second, looks like you might need to update statistics on your index more often than an automatic update would. I have seen cases when, in a situation akin to yours, I had to update stats every 10 minutes, due to excessive inserts. That was back on 2005, though.

Comment: Not sure what benefit adding the `Timestamp` to the index itself would bring - since it's the second column in the index, this index won't be able to be used for sorting by `Timestamp` ..... (I'll try it at the office later on and report back). Also: updating the stats didn't seem to help :-( (which was a bit confusing to me)

Comment: @marc_s, the index will be sorting by UserId, then (within each user) by Timestamp. This will allow you to quickly find last (i.e. max()) date for each of them. Included column does not provide such a benefit, afair.

Comment: Roger - you're absolutely right. This index seems to work better than what I had. Thanks!

Comment: You rock, Roger! This works **like a charm** - even after I insert (and re-insert) millions of more dummy rows - I still have sub-second performance - WOW! Thanks!

Comment: @marc_s, you're welcome :). But in any case, I would recommend keeping an eye on that index (and maybe table in general), since this one is naturally prone to fragmentation - new entries for old users will always fall into the middle of it. Eventually you will come to an update / rebuild schedule which will keep everyone happy.

Answer (score 2):

Try this query and see how it performs with your original index or with the modified suggested by @Roger Wolf:

```
SELECT u.UserId, a.LastLogDate 
FROM dbo.Users u
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT UserId, Max([TimeStamp]) AS LastLogDate
    FROM dbo.ActionLog 
    WHERE userid <> 'user' -- the user to filter out
    GROUP BY UserId
) a ON a.UserId = u.UserId
```

If it sucks I'll delete the answer :)

Comment: It doesn't suck at all - it's just as good, if not even better, than what Roger suggested. Performance is stable and very fast - thanks!

Comment: @marc_s Ah ok, that's good to know. Obviously I didn't have a large amount of suitable data to test it with. Good to know it performed well.

Answer (score -1):

Erase the subselect:

```
SELECT u.UserId, Max(a.TimeStamp) As LastLogDate
FROM   dbo.Users u
,      dob.ActionLog a
Where  a.UserId = u.UserId
Group By u.UserId;
```

Then think about getting the other columns.

Comment: OK - but then I'd recommend **not** using the "comma-separated" list of tables (this style has been deprecated with the SQL:92 standard - more than 20 years ago!) - use **proper** ANSI JOIN syntax!

Comment: hell, yeah. but since I'm forced to use some old crap at work that has PROBS with prober JOIN syntax, shit is going to happen :( thanx!